# Show without expanding that the two determinants are equal

Tags: algebra-precalculus, matrices, determinant

Let
$$
 A=        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & a^2 & b^2 & c^2\\
        a^2 & 0 & z^2 & y^2\\
        b^2 & z^2 & 0 & x^2\\
        c^2 & y^2 & x^2 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
B=        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & ax & by & cz\\
        ax & 0 & cz & by\\
        by & cz & 0 & ax\\
        cz & by & ax & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Show that $\det(A)=\det(B)$.

I have tried by multiplying and dividing $xyz$ and $abc$ to symmetric rows and columns; however, I was unable to take out the common. So please help.

Comment: I guess it's det(A) = det(B)?

Comment: @GregP. OP is using the notation $|M| = \det M$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing something clever, you could observe that each of your determinants has only nine non-zero terms. So you could just compute both determinants (as polynomials) and compare them.

Comment: yes but he does not want to expand the determinants... so I guess he does not want to compute them either.

Comment: @anderstood My impression was that what he didn't want (because he had tried it and failed) was to pull out common factors from some rows or columns, to simplify the determinant.

Comment: @anderstood Now I think you're right; I was concentrating on the question and ignored the title.

Comment: Anyway this seems to be homework, so he'll probably get the solution from his teacher... :)

Comment: I want to solve the problem without expanding the determinant, as it would be a lengthy method to expand any row or column of A and B and then compare and equate them.Further these type of questions may come in our exams where time is very less,so the shortest and simplest method would be appreciated

Comment: @Sourajit By expanding, I meant the sum over permutations formula, not expansion by minors. Comparing the two expansions is very easy, because, as I said, there are only nine non-0 terms. It took me less than 2 minutes, and didn't even require pencil & paper.

Comment: @Andreas Can you please illustrate the method as till now I have not learnt the sum of permutation formulae and know only expansion by minors.So I would be grateful if you please show it here

Comment: @Sourajit On the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant look in the section headed "n x n matrices" for the Leibniz formula.  Note that that section includes, after the general n x n information, the explicit formula for the 3 x 3 case.